# Transactions with data to contract functions

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have following contract deployed on my local test RPC

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract cntrct {
  uint public aaa; 

  function run() payable public
  {
    aaa += msg.value;
  }

  function reader() public returns(uint)
  {
    return aaa;
  }
}
```

I know this doesn't make much sense but it's for testing purposes. So first I need to generate the transaction data, so I use:

```
var run = web3.utils.sha3("run()").substring(0, 10);
//Output: 0xc0406226
```

Now I send the data inside a transaction to the contract, which should trigger the `run` function.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    to:toAddr, 
    gasPrice: '30000000000', 
    from:fromAddr, 
    data: run, // = 0xc0406226
    value: "1000000000000000000"});
```

But my `aaa` variable stays `0` which means the `run()` function never ran. I check the `aaa` variable with the `reader()` function:

```
contract.methods.reader().call().then(console.log)
```

EDIT: Here is the complete code I run in node:

```
const fromAddr = '0x...';
const toAddr = '0x...';
const contractName = ':cntrct';
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
const solc = require('solc');
const input = fs.readFileSync('Token.sol');
const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts[contractName].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[contractName].interface); 
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, toAddr); //const?
contract.options.address = toAddr;

//Deploy contract
var deployed = contract.deploy({
    data: bytecode, 
    arguments: [[]]})
  .send({
    from: toAddr, 
    gas: 4700000, 
    gasPrice: '30000000000'}, 
    function(error) {console.log(error)});

//Make a test transaction
var run = web3.utils.sha3("run()").substring(0, 10);
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    to:toAddr, 
    gasPrice: '30000000000', 
    from:fromAddr, 
    data: run, 
    value: "1000000000000000000"});

//call reader function
contract.methods.reader().call().then(console.log);
//This returns Promise{...} 0
```

Comment: Is the transaction successful? Does `toAddr` match the address of `contract`?

Comment: Yes, transaction showed up in my testRPC and both addresses were defined correctly. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: But was the transaction _successful_?

Comment: In remix, the contract's balance went up by exactly 1 ether so I'm assuming it did?

Comment: How are you checking the balance in Remix? If you call `aaa()` in Remix, does it show the value you expect?

Comment: I just repeated your steps and it works fine. I deployed under Solidity 0.4.19, Truffle 4.0.6. Output: truffle(development)> c.reader.call()
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
truffle(development)> var run = web3.sha3('run()').substring(0,10);
undefined truffle(development)> web3.eth.sendTransaction({to: c.address, from: a[0], gasPrice: '30000000000', data: run, value: '1000000000000000000'});
'0xc99105bccdaf2b7803b3cdb359e0fe9fcdb59ff2608a2805b0dcc79e77f50190'
truffle(development)> c.reader.call()
{ [String: '1000000000000000000'] s: 1, e: 18, c: [ 10000 ] }
truffle(development)>

Comment: I clicked on `aaa` and then on details and it shows it has a value of 100..Wei (1 Ether,) this means the `run()` function did run, right?

Comment: @AdamKipnis Thanks alot for testing this!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I was looking at the transaction value, my bad! when I click on `aaa` after the transaction it says `0: uint256: 0`

Comment: As @AdamKipnis showed, what you describe works fine, so there's not enough information here for someone to debug it for you. You believe the transaction is succeeding because you've somehow seen the balance of the contract go up, but you didn't answer my question about how. I continue to assume that the transaction is failing.

Comment: Sorry, In remix I check the balances simply in the drop down account menu (with the ten default accounts.) I'll provide some more code.